# Duda python ordenar lista

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo problemas con este ejercicio:

Para N (constante) productos diferentes (lista producto), se ingresa la cantidad vendida
(lista cantidad) y el precio (lista precio). Imprimir un listado “producto- cantidad -monto
recaudado” por la venta de cada producto ordenado de mayor a menor por monto.

Y este es mi programa:

> 

```
def ingresar_matriz ():
    matriz = []
    n = int(input("ingrese la cantidad de elementos:\n"))
    for i in range(n):
        cantidad = int(input("ingrese la cantidad del elemento uno a uno:\n"))
        precio = float(input("ingrese el precio de ese elemento:\n"))
        matriz.append([i,cantidad,(precio*cantidad)])
        

    return matriz

def ordenar_matriz (a):
    a.reverse
    a.sort(reverse=True)

def main():
    matriz = ingresar_matriz()
    ordenada = ordenar_matriz(matriz)
    print(ordenada)


main()
```

Lo que no entiendo muy bien es como puedo ordenar la matriz a partir de su elemento en la posicion 2 (cantidad recaudada total)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es la función `ordenar_matriz` que necesitas:

```
def ordenar_matriz(a):
    a.reverse
    a.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
    return a
```

Usamos el parámetro `key` para indicar a `sort` como comparar dos elementos. La función recibe un elemento de la matriz, de la forma `[secuencia, cantidad, valor]`. El elemento que nos interesa para comparar el valor, que vendria estando en la posición 2.

**¿Qué es lambda?**

`sort` requiere que proporciones una función que devuelve el valor por el cual comparar. En este caso es valor, que está en la posición 2 dentro de cada elemento, y voy a definir una función `evaluar` que haga este trabajo.

En una primera versión, la definiré como función interna, dado que sólo la necesito dentro de `ordenar_matriz`.

```
def ordenar_matriz(a):
    def evalua(x):
        return x[2]

    a.reverse
    a.sort(key=evalua, reverse=True)
    return a
```

Notese que paso a key el **nombre** de la función (sin paréntesis), no una **llamada** a la función.

Bueno, todo esto es mucho escribir y se ocupan muchas líneas, así que existe la alternativa de usar **lambda**, que permite crear una función anónima (no tiene nombre) consistente de una sola expresión, que viene a ser el valor retornado, que es todo lo que necesito.

En lugar de escribir

```
def evalua(x):
    return x[2]
```

simplemente escribo

```
lambda x: x[2]
```

y se lo paso directamente a `sort`.

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
```

Finalmente, la función debe retornar la matriz ordenada, por lo que agregamos un `return`.

**El método sort(*, key=None, reverse=False)**

Este método ordena la lista in situ (se modifica internamente), usando unicamente comparaciones de tipo <. Las excepciones no son capturadas internamente: si alguna comparación falla, la operación entera de ordenación falla (Y la lista probablemente haya quedado modificada parcialmente).

El método sort() acepta dos parámetros, que solo pueden pasarse por nombre (keyword-only arguments):

El parámetro `key` especifica una función de un argumento que se usa para obtener, para cada elemento de la lista, un valor concreto o clave (`key`) a usar en las operaciones de comparación (Por ejemplo, `key=str.lower`). El elemento clave para cada elemento se calcula una única vez y se reutiliza para todo el proceso de ordenamiento. El valor por defecto, `None`, hace que la lista se ordene comparando directamente los elementos, sin obtener valores clave.

Comment: Hola Candid, me quedo bastante claro y me sirvio lo que me contaste, Ahora que significa en particular el elemento "lambda" al que le asignaste key? Siempre tendria que usarla para la funcion ordenar en base a un parametro?

Comment: @Cristobal. Agregue la explicación en la respuesta. Revisala.

Comment: Hola @Cristobal .Si te parece correcta la explicación y te ha servido, lo mejor que puedes hacer es aceptar la respuesta en forma de agradecimiento, y por qué no, darle un voto positivo!

Comment: Perdon es que soy un poco nuevo, como puedo darle un voto positivo?